# Printing list, strings and dict within one string using format in Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting

I wish to format a string necessary for querying a database as follows:

```
SELECT "field1", "field2" FROM "measurement" where "status"=0 AND "node"='name1' LIMIT 10
```

the following comes from a dict:

- `field1`, `field2`
- `measurement`
- `node` and `name1`
- `10`

The dict is as follows:

```
conf = {
  'fields': ['field1', 'field2'],
  'measurement': 'measurement',
  'limit': 10,
  'tags': {'node': 'name1'}
}
```

I am able to format the string a part of the string (without the `tags`) as follows:

```
    QUERY = 'SELECT "{}" FROM {} WHERE "status"=0 LIMIT {}'.format(
             '","'.join(conf['fields'],
             conf['measurement'],
             conf['limit'])
```

This provides me:

```
SELECT "field1", "field2" FROM measurement WHERE "status"=0 LIMIT 10
```

### Problem

The key value pair within the `tags` is in many case *dynamic* i.e. there is no previously known `key` (in this example `node`)

For the string:

```
QUERY = 'SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE "status"=0 AND "{}"=\'{}\' LIMIT {}
```

I wish to fill the string format `AND "{}"=\'{}\'` *dynamically* (without prior knowledge of the key value pair within `tags`

How do I achieve this?

I am not sure if:

```
QUERY = 'SELECT "{}" FROM {} WHERE "status"=0 AND "{}"=\'{}\' LIMIT {}'.format(
                '","'.join(conf['fields']),
                conf['measurement'],
                **conf['tags'],
                conf['limit']
            )
```

works as it throws the following `SyntaxError`:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument unpacking
```

Comment: How does your `conf` look like, can you add that

Comment: it is already added: see the `conf` dict

Comment: @Shan-Desai is `tags` always just a single key-value pair?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 for the initial case yes.

Comment: The first string you have can only be represented in python if we use `"""` , since you both have single and double quotes in there, is that correct? also why do you have `"node"='name1'` and not `node=name1` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh The query language for the database expects it in that format, if it doesn't follow that rule the query is invalid. I wrapped everything in single quotes because the query has a mixture of single and double quotes.

Comment: what python library are you using, I am sure there is a better way then formatting strings to create query with params

Comment: [influxdb-python](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the formatted string using the dictionary `conf['tags']` beforehand to make it easier to apply to `QUERY`

```
conf = {
  'fields': ['field1', 'field2'],
  'measurement': 'measurement',
  'limit': 10,
  'tags': {'node': 'name1'}
}

#Create the string using dictionary
dict_str = ''.join('"{}"=\'{}\''.format(key,value) for key, value in conf['tags'].items())

#Create the final format string
QUERY = 'SELECT "{}" FROM "{}" WHERE "status"=0 AND {} LIMIT {}'.format(
                '","'.join(conf['fields']),
                conf['measurement'],
                dict_str,
                conf['limit']
            )
print(QUERY)
```

The output will be

```
SELECT "field1","field2" FROM "measurement" WHERE "status"=0 AND "node"='name1' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: works for me! I had a look into the Client Library there might be something in the lines where one makes a generic query of everything and then parse it using the `tags` dict but your solution is cleaner and easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.6 and above there is a new way of string formating using f-strings as specified [here (python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). I am not sure I understood your request but that's what I thought you meant:

```
key = list(conf['tags'].keys())[0]

QUERY = f"""SELECT {conf['fields'][0]}, {conf['fields'][1]} FROM "{conf['measurement']}" WHERE "status"=0 AND "{key}"='{conf['tags'][key]}' LIMIT {conf['limit']}"""
```

That results in this string:

```
SELECT "field1", "field2" FROM "measurement" WHERE "status"=0 AND "node"='name1' LIMIT 10
```